# Is there a way to pass in a UTC offset to a Moment utc object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to pass a UTC offset (i.e. -25200, or -0700) to a moment.utc() constructor built time?

I.e:

```
const timeUtc = moment.utc('Sun, 25 Sep 2016 12:30:00', 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');

const timeDifference = '-25200';
```

Any method to call to convert timeUtc moment object to a moment object in the timezone with the utc offset of the timeDifference?

Comment: Note that I corrected two errors in your input.  I assume these are copy/paste issues, but 1) you had 2016 twice, and 2) don't use the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Moment has a `utcOffset` function that can be used to set the offset.  However, it's not expecting input in terms of seconds as a string.  You must divide to get minutes, which will also coerce it to a number.

```
const timeWithOffset = moment(timeUtc).utcOffset(timeDifference / 60);
```

This also is creating a clone, as not to mutate the original value.

If you call `.format()` on this with your example inputs, you'll get `"2016-09-25T05:30:00-07:00"`

This correctly converts from UTC to the offset provided.  If instead you meant that the original value was already in that offset, then pass a `true` as a second parameter to the `utcOffset` function and you'll get `"2016-09-25T12:30:00-07:00"` instead.

Note that I'm assuming your input offset represents UTC-7.  If it's actually UTC+7, you'll want to multiply by -1 in there also.